# Remove role for offline members

Tags: discord.js

I need some help...
I've been trying to make my bot searching 24/7 for offline members which got offline and the role still on them and remove it
(The bot is running on Heroku server)

I have this code for adding and removing a certain role with the use of game activity.
I tried to play with forEach() function and i got stuck

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  const guild = newMember.guild;
  const playingRole = guild.roles.find(role => role.id === '671631357725638656');

  if (newMember.user.bot || oldMember.presence.status !== newMember.presence.status) return;

  const oldGame = oldMember.presence.game && [0, 1].includes(oldMember.presence.game.type) ? true : false;
  const newGame = newMember.presence.game && [0, 1].includes(newMember.presence.game.type) ? true : false;
   
   if (!oldGame && newGame) {         
    newMember.addRole(playingRole)
  } else if (oldGame && !newGame) {  
    newMember.removeRole(playingRole)
  } 
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord JS V12:

```js
Client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => { // We don't really need to use oldPresence here.
    if (newPresence.guild.id !== "GuildID") {return false}; // Did this because it will listen to presenceUpdate events from all guilds. You may remove this line if you'd like.
    const Role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get("RoleID"); // Finding the required role.
    if (!Role) {return console.error("No role found.")}; // If the role doesn't exist we return an error.

    if (newPresence.status == "offline") { // online - user is online; idle - user is AFK; offline - user is offline or invisible; dnd - user is in Do Not Disturb;
        newPresence.member.roles.remove(Role).catch(e => {console.error(e)}); // Removing the role since the user is offline.
    } else {
        newPresence.member.roles.add(Role).catch(e => {console.error(e)}); // Adding the role since the user is Online/Idle/Do Not Disturb
    };
});
```

Discord JS V11:

```js
Client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldGuildMember, newGuildMember) => {
    if (newGuildMember.guild.id !== "GuildID") {return false};
    const Role = newGuildMember.guild.roles.get("RoleID");
    if (!Role) {return console.error("No role found.")};

    if (newGuildMember.presence.status == "offline") {
        newGuildMember.removeRole(Role).catch(e => {console.error(e)});
    } else {
        newGuildMember.addRole(Role).catch(e => {console.error(e)});
    };
});
```

Comment: I've edited the brackets and it works like a charm!
Thanks a lot!